# How can you center the mouse pointer to make it a crosshair?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I made a custom cursor on GIMP for a game and I want the mouse to be centered on the cursor. So the tip of the normal arrow pointer is in the center of the crosshair.

Any ideas?

I have already hidden the other cursor and displayed the new one, I just want to make it centered.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for the cursor, set its `center` coords to the mouse position when a `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` event occurs and blit the cursor image at the rect.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
# pg.mouse.set_visible(False)
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')

CURSOR_IMG = pg.Surface((40, 40), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.circle(CURSOR_IMG, pg.Color('white'), (20, 20), 20, 2)
pg.draw.circle(CURSOR_IMG, pg.Color('white'), (20, 20), 2)
# Create a rect which we'll use as the blit position of the cursor.
cursor_rect = CURSOR_IMG.get_rect()

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            # If the mouse is moved, set the center of the rect
            # to the mouse pos. You can also use pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # if you're not in the event loop.
            cursor_rect.center = event.pos

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    # Blit the image at the rect's topleft coords.
    screen.blit(CURSOR_IMG, cursor_rect)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first draw a rectangle around the surface and place the center of rectangle on the position of the mouse and finally blit the surface on the rectangle

```
elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
    cursor_rect = CURSOR_IMG.get_rect(center = event.pos)
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like `pygame.event.set_grab(True)`, it should work and keep your mouse pointer in the middle of the screen for a crosshair functionality.